# WebSVN accept untrusted HTTPS certificate

Tags: https, certificate, svn

I am using websvn with a remote repository. This repository uses **https** protocol. After having configured websvn I get on the websvn webpage:

```
svn --non-interactive --config-dir /tmp list --xml --username '***' --password '***' 'https://scm.gforge.....'
OPTIONS of 'https://scm.gforge.....': Server certificate verification failed: issuer is not trusted
```

I don't know how to indicate to websvn to execute svn command in order to accept and to store the certificate. Does someone knows how to do it?

**UPDATE:**

It works! In order to have something which is well organized I have updated the WebSVN config file to relocate the subversion config directory to **/etc/subversion** which is the default path for debian:

```
$config->setSvnConfigDir('/etc/subversion');
```

In **/etc/subversion/servers** I have created a group and associated the certificate to trust:

```
[groups]
my_repo = my.repo.url.to.trust

[global]
ssl-trust-default-ca = true
store-plaintext-passwords = no

[my_repo]
ssl-authority-files = /etc/apache2/ssl/my.repo.url.to.trust.crt
```

Comment: Are you using Windows? Or Linux?

Comment: Linux (Debian lenny)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two possible methods available to resolve this.

Option 1:

su to the user websvn is running as and perform `svn log https://your.secure.repo.com/repo/`  against the target server. Subversion should then ask you to accept the certificate and you could choose to do so on a permanent basis. Then the cert will be okay to use.

Option 2:

Again, as the user the websvn process runs on, edit ~/.subversion/servers and add to the [global] section;

```
ssl-authority-files = /home/websvn/ssl/CAcert1.pem
```

If your after something quicky, then option 1 is the one to use, otherwise go for option two

**Correction**

As the poster pointed out in the command, svn is being called with the --config-dir option. This means that subversion will expect its configurations to be located in that directory, in this case /tmp. Thus copy the servers and config from ~/.subversion/ to /tmp directory and the subversion client will use those.

Comment: This will work, but only if the OP is using *nix

Comment: This would be true, presumption was made as command refereed to /tmp. 

However on windows there is a .subversion settings for a user profile (%USERPROFILE%\Application Data\Subversion\\) but if your running it as a system account I am hazarding you could use the %APPDATA%\Subversion folder to accomplish the same.

Comment: I have tried both options without success

Comment: Do you have the output from both or is it the same? Also I note you config dir is set to /tmp so add the file servers there. More specifically copy your modified servers file to /tmp/servers

Answer (score 3):

There is a third, simpler option. It is possible to configure websvn to trust all server certificates. In `include/config.php` add or uncomment the following line:

```
$config->setTrustServerCert();
```